# Saving recorded audio blob [JS]

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I am recording user voice through microphone and saving it as a file on Google Drive (using GDrive API). I was having no issues doing this and listening to the audio that is uploaded to drive when I listen to it in the browser. However, when I download the file from GDrive, it gets downloaded without an extension (kind of like a textedit document).

I tried to modify the extension of the downloaded file and play it but it doesn't play on QuickTime, VLC or even Audacity etc.

Here's how I am recording the audio

```js
function recordVisitorMsg() {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio: true
        })
        .then(stream => {
            const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            mediaRecorder.start();
            const audioChunks = [];
            mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
                audioChunks.push(event.data);
            });

            mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
                audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, {
                    'type': 'audio/mp3'
                });
                const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);

                const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
                audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
                audio.play();
            });

            setTimeout(() => {
                mediaRecorder.stop();
            }, 3000);
        });
}
```

Here's how I am uploading to Drive.

```js
form = new FormData();
form.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], {
        type: 'application/json'
    }));


    form.append('audio-file', audioBlob);

let refresh_request = {
            body: post_body,
            method: "POST",
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            })
        }

        // trimmed the secret keys code for length, not necessary here 
        fetch(refresh_url, refresh_request).then(response => {
            return (response.json());
        }).then(response_json => {
            console.log(response_json);
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('post', 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&fields=id');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + response_json.access_token);
            xhr.responseType = 'json';
            xhr.onload = () => {
                console.log(xhr.response.id); // Retrieve uploaded file ID.
            };
            xhr.send(form);
        });
```

I am new to this so please excuse if there's some minor issue wrong in this process. Again, it plays fine when I play it from within GDrive in the browser. The problem is when I download -- it comes out without the extension. Manual extension/modification doesn't help either to play the file in any player. Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this solves the problem entirely but I think it would be a good start to set the correct `mimeType` when creating the `Blob`. Unfortunately there is no browser which allows to record MP3s with the `MediaRecorder`. The default `mimeType` in Chrome is for example `'audio/webm'`. You can read the `mimeType` from the `MediaRecorder` to set it when creating the `Blob`.

```
audioBlob = new Blob(
    audioChunks,
    { type: mediaRecorder.mimeType }
);
```

It may also help to create a `File` instead of a `Blob`. It allows you to set the filename and thus the extension. A quick and dirty way is to parse the `mimeType` like this.

```
audioBlob = new File(
    audioChunks,
    `my-file.${mediaRecorder.mimeType.match(/\/([\w\d]+);?/)[1]}`,
    { type: mediaRecorder.mimeType }
);
```

In Chrome this should be equal to the following hardcoded version.

```
audioBlob = new File(
    audioChunks,
    'my-file.webm',
    { type: 'audio/webm' }
);
```

Comment: I was having the same issue here and the second code snippet (where you dynamically set the mimeType) worked great. Some code examples online are using 'audio/mp3' as the mimetype which works fine when playing it in the browser after you record it but does not work when exporting as a file. Thanks so much, been struggling with this one for a while!